# Prevent SelectionChanged on loading DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I need a DataGridView to load without triggering the SelectionChanged event.
It seems that when it's loaded it must select a cell that triggers this unwanted event.
Is there a way to circumvent it?

Answer (score 2):

You could remove the event handler when loading the `DataGridView`.

```csharp
private void LoadDataGridView()
{
   TheDataGridView.SelectionChanged -= TheDataGridView_SelectionChanged; // Remove the handler.
   try
   {
      // Load the data grid view.
   }
   finally
   {
      TheDataGridView.SelectionChanged += TheDataGridView_SelectionChanged; // Add the handler back.
   }
}
```